# svd doesn't return correct dimension

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra

I have a matrix with dimension (22,2) and I want to decompose it using SVD. SVD in numpy doesn't return the correct dimensions though.I'd expect dimensions like `(22,22), (22),(22,2)`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned dimensions are correct. The `uu` and `vvh` matrices are always **square matrices**, while depending on the software `s` can be an array with just the singular values (as in numpy) or a diagonal matrix with the dimension of the original matrix (as in MATLAB, for instance).

The dimensions of the `uu` matrix is the number of rows of the original matrix, while the dimension of the `vvh` matrix is the number of columns of the original matrix. This can never change or you would be computing something else instead of the SVD.

To reconstruct the original matrix from the decomposition in numpy we need to make `s` into a matrix with the proper dimension. For square matrices it's easy, just `np.diag(s)` is enough. Since your original matrix is not square and it has more rows than columns, then we can use something like

```py
S = np.vstack([np.diag(s), np.zeros((20, 2))])
```

Then we get a `S` matrix which is a diagonal matrix with the singular values concatenated with a zero matrix. In the end, `uu` is 22x22, `S` is `22x2` and `vvh` is `2x2`. Multiplying `uu @ S @ vvh` will give the original matrix back.